# OpenCV Error: Bad argument (bytes must be 16, 32, or 64) in BriefDescriptorExtractorImpl

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I am trying to detect feature points using SURF and descriptor extractor using BRIEF.

```
cv::Ptr<Feature2D> detector = xfeatures2d::SurfFeatureDetector::create(400);
Mat descriptors_img1, descriptors_img2;


//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
detector->detect(img1, kp1);
detector->detect(img2, kp2);

cv::Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = xfeatures2d::BriefDescriptorExtractor::create(400);

extractor->compute(img1, kp1, descriptors_img1 );
extractor->compute(img2, kp2, descriptors_img2 );
```

But I am getting error

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (bytes must be 16, 32, or 64) in BriefDescriptorExtractorImpl, file /home/user/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/xfeatures2d/src/brief.cpp, line 185
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/user/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/xfeatures2d/src/brief.cpp:185: error: (-5) bytes must be 16, 32, or 64 in function BriefDescriptorExtractorImpl
```

can anyone explain about this error and also how to solve it.
I am using OpenCV3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BriefDescriptorExtractor(int bytes=32,bool use_orientation = false)
```

The first argument should be of bytes.
So from your code, remove the argument 400 and try. The first argument should be of 2^ and not 400.
change your code from

```
cv::Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = xfeatures2d::BriefDescriptorExtractor::create(400);
```

to

```
cv::Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = xfeatures2d::BriefDescriptorExtractor::create();
```